# Javascript add row to Javascript generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone tell me where to add the small piece of code to have one row added on top of the table containing the numbers. I only need one row added, but with the code supplies beneath, 15 cells are placed on top of eachother, I think the code places a cel for every name.

```
$("#myTable tbody").prepend("<tr><td>...contents...</td></tr>");
```

This code above is the code where it should fit in somewhere.

I tried to add it before this part beneath

```
$('#players table tr').each(function()
```

This is the code where it should be placed in somewhere

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function() {

     var players = {
        Joop   : ["6","8","16","18","26","28","32","36","38","41"],
        Marijke: ["7","10","14","18","24","29","30","34","39","40"],
        Michel : ["4","5","11","16","21","27","33","36","42","44"],
        Mario  : ["6","9","18","25","32","35","39","40","43","45"],
        Diana  : ["2","6","8","17","22","23","33","36","42","45"],
        Agnes  : ["3","5","10","15","26","29","32","37","41","44"],
        Chris  : ["5","7","8","9","11","12","16","28","30","32"],
        Jeannette: ["1","2","4","7","8","11","13","28","30","38"],
        Wieger: ["1","2","3","7","10","13","14","22","23","27"],
        Anita: ["6","13","15","17","21","26","32","33","43","45"],
        Thea: ["1","3","5","7","10","17","19","20","22","38"],
        Danny: ["3","7","11","15","22","28","32","37","40","43"],
        Cindy: ["2","4","16","18","21","24","33","38","41","44"],
        Hanneke: ["1","3","4","12","18","21","25","30","36","40"],
        Willem: ["3","9","17","21","27","33","35","39","41","42"]
    },

    draws = [
        {
        when: 'Datum: Zaterdag 08-08-2009',
              picks:[2, 13, 15, 18, 21, 41]
        },

        {
        when: 'Datum: Zaterdag 15-08-2009',
          picks:[6, 19, 24, 25, 35, 37]
        },

        {
        when: 'Datum: Zaterdag 22-08-2009',
          picks:[8, 17, 23, 26, 37, 42]
        },

    {
        when: 'Datum: Zaterdag 29-08-2009',
          picks:[1, 11, 31, 39, 42, 43]
        }
    ];



    var buildPlayers = function(){
        var cont = $("#players"), table = $('<table></table>');
        for( player in players ){
        if ( players.hasOwnProperty( player ) ) {
            var tr = $('<tr><th>' + player + '</th></tr>').appendTo(table),
                len = players[player].length;

            for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var td = $('<td/>') 
         td.addClass("loss")
        .addClass("pick_" + players[player][i]) // add the class to the td  
        .text( players[player][i] )
        .appendTo ( tr );

        }


        var winning = $('<td>').addClass('winning-col').appendTo(tr);

            cont.append( table );
        }
        }
    };


    var buildDraws = function(){
        var cont = $("#draws");
        for(var i = 0; i < draws.length; i++){
        var html = ["<div class='draw'>","<h4 class='drawNum'>Trekking "+(i+1) +"</h3></p>","<div class='date'>"+draws[i].when+"</div>","<ol class='picks'>"];

        for(var j = 0; j < draws[i].picks.length; j++) {
            var img = '<img src="http://www.lotto.nl/static/images/ballen/lotto/l'
         + draws[i].picks[j]
         + '.jpg" alt="'
         + draws[i].picks[j]
         + '" />';
            html.push("<li>"+img+"</li>");
            showWin(draws[i].picks[j]);
        }



        html.push("</ol>","</div>");
        cont.append(html.join(""));
        }
    };

    var showWin = function(winNum){
        $(".pick_"+winNum).removeClass("loss").addClass("win");
    };


    $(function(){
        buildPlayers();
        buildDraws();
        function countWinning() {
        $('#players table tr').each(function() {
            var winning = $('td.win', this), total = 0;
            winning.each(function(i,num) {
            total+= parseInt( $(this).text(), 10);
            });

          $(".winning-col", this)
      .text($("td.win", this).length)
      .addClass("hilighted");

        });
        }
        countWinning();
    });


    })();

    </script>
```

Comment: If you show us the markup, it will make things a whole lot easier

Comment: here is the link. http://www.coldcharlie.nl/lotto/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These will all add a row to the beginning of the table:

Using [insertBefore](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/insertBefore):

```
$('<tr><td>Stuff</td></tr>').insertBefore('#players > tbody > tr:first');
```

Using [before](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/before#content):

```
$('#players > tbody > tr:first').before('<tr><td>Stuff</td></tr>');
```

Using [prependTo](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prependTo#selector):

```
$("<tr><td>some data</td></tr>").prependTo("#players > tbody");
```

Using [prepend](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prepend#selector):

```
$("#players tbody").prepend("<tr><td>...contents...</td></tr>");
```

If the table is generated on the fly, you might want to try omitting the `tbody` tag from the selector, e.g.:

```
$('<tr><td>Stuff</td></tr>').insertBefore('#players > tr:first');
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont usually do this, but since i wrote about this a few days ago **at length** i will give you a link to that:

http://notetodogself.blogspot.com/2009/08/javascript-insert-table-rows-table-body.html